Flutter schedule push notifications problem
I'm writing a tasker program, and I need to send notification before 24 hours of deadline. I'm trying to send notification by schedule but I've a problem
It worsks but when I add the schedule it brokes
> Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.LocalDateTime
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 16 more

>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
I/Process (21810): Sending signal. PID: 21810 SIG: 9

this is my main.dart file:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService();
  await notificationService.initNotification();
  tz.initializeTimeZones();
  await FirebaseApi().initNotifications();
  runApp(Tasker());
}

this is my Notification class:


class NotificationService {
      final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
          FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    
      Future<void> initNotification() async {
        AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
            const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    
        var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
          android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
        );
    
        await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
      }
    
      notificationDetails() {
        return const NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            'channel_id',
            'channel_name',
            importance: Importance.max,
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Future<void> showNotification(
          {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payload}) async {
        return notificationsPlugin.show(
            id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
      }
    
      Future scheduleNotification(
          {int id = 0,
          String? title,
          String? body,
          String? payload,
          required DateTime scheduleNotificationDateTime}) async {
        return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
          id,
          title,
          body,
          tz.TZDateTime.from(scheduleNotificationDateTime, tz.local),
          await notificationDetails(),
          androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
          uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
              UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
          
        );
      }
    }

and this is the button I use for testing:
onTap: () {
            _notificationService.scheduleNotification(
                 title: 'User',
                 body: 'it works',
                 scheduleNotificationDateTime: DateTime(2024, 7, 8, 13, 1));
              },

but if I use function 'showNotification' without 'scheduleNotificationDateTime' it works
onTap: () {
            _notificationService.showNotification(
                 title: 'User',
                 body: 'it works',
        );
              },

I also added theese strings to my AndroidManifest.xml
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
> <uses-permission
> android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

I tried to change build.gradle and AndroidManifest.xml by YouTube tutorials but the problem is exists.
